# Visual Studio 2017 Installer Project not showing any dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, deployment

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 (version 15.4.4), with the Visual Studio Installer Extension.  I have an existing C# .Net Core 1.1 console application with four Nuget packages listed as dependencies in my solution, and I have added an Installer project to this solution to build a Windows application setup program.

I've ticked the "primary output" option to include the built DLL, however when I look at the Dependencies folder in the Solution Explorer it is empty.  Right-clicking "Refresh Dependencies" on this folder does not do anything for me.

When I build the release for the installer project, the end .msi file and setup.exe don't include or otherwise install any of the nuget packages.

The output console when I build the setup package just lists my runtimeconfig.json file and dll when it is packaging, and the runtimeconfig.json file only has the following in it:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "1.1.2"
    }
  }
}
```

Have I missed something?  What might I need to do to get the nuget packages recognized as dependencies and added to the install files so they get deployed by my setup.exe?

Comment: Could be that the Installer Projects extension doesn't support .Net Core. It wouldn't surprise me, as it was only developed to allow legacy .vdproj deployment projects to survive.

Comment: @Jaysen Ollerenshaw, Agree with stuartd. At this moment, this Visual Studio Installer Extension not support .NET Core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks stuartd and Leo Liu.  For the moment I've followed the method of Build > Publish > publish to a folder, and then zipping that folder up for distribution.

I did have to copy the dll file into the obj\x64\Release\win-x64 directory after building for this to work.  I was getting an error that the file wasn't found.

This solution means I need to provide some more steps to the end users about how to set up the program to run, but at least it works.